# Cannot find kendo-ui drop down using capybara

Tags: rspec, kendo-ui, capybara

I know kendo-ui hides elements from view. unselectable="on" However, I am unable to find a specific drop down or it's options using capybara.

[Please see image here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K2RHK.png)

I've tried adding the `:visible => false` tag to a find, but that does not seem to help, either. (or it does, and I'm using the wrong selector.)

I just want to the be able to select one of the options in the drop down.

EDIT: "You don't show the actual HTML from the elements that actually become visible on the page," ~Thomas Walpole

[Here it is!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mkAkx.png)

Comment: Show the code you've tried

Comment: Some of what I've tried:
#find('#systemType > option:nth-child(2)').select_option #Select "bar system"
#find('#systemType', :visible => false, :text=>'Bar System', :match=>:prefer_exact).click
#find('span.k-widget.k-dropdown.k-header.input').click
#find('[id=systemType]', :visible => false).click
#select("Bar System", from: '[id=systemType]', :visible => false).select_option
#find("input[value='bar']", :visible => false).click
within( all('[id^="qq5_"]')[0] ) do
        find('span.k-widget.k-dropdown.k-header.input', :visible => false).sibling('span').click        end

Comment: Using the `visible: false` option only makes sense as a step towards locating other elements that are actually  visible (see my answer).  This is because a user can't (and therefore neither should you in tests) interact with non-visible elements, so `click` on a non-visible element is meaningless.  Additionally the actual visible elements on your page are not `<select>` or `<option>` elements so `select` and `select_option` don't make sense either.

Answer (score 0):

You don't show the actual HTML from the elements that actually become visible on the page, it'll be much further down the HTML and probably with an id of 'systemType_listbox`(based on the`aria-owns` attribute on the wrapping span.  But, something like

```
find('select#systemType', visible: :hidden).sibling('span').click # trigger the opening of the dropdown widget
find('#systemType-list li', text: 'Bumper').click # select the Bumper option from the now visible list
```

will probably do want you want.

Comment: "You don't show the actual HTML from the elements that actually become visible on the page". Oh! You're right, and that helps a ton.

Comment: @SarahEdwards Ok, I've update the second find in my answer to match the id of the element you added to the question, does that work for you now?  If not, what error exactly is it producing?

Comment: I'm seeing the following error: `Capybara::ElementNotFound: Unable to find non-visible css "select#systemType"`

Comment: @SarahEdwards That would imply the initial HTML you posted isn't actually on the page (or you're not actually using a JS capable driver - which wouldn't make sense when trying to tests JS driven widgets).  If a `select` element with id of `systemType` and style of `display: none` was actually in the page it would be found.  You can try swapping to `visible: false` which will find both visible and non-visible elements, but it really sounds like your tests isn't actually on the page you think it is.

Comment: _lightbulb_ That's because it's in an I-Frame.

Comment: @SarahEdwards AH - that would explain it, you need to use `within_frame` to switch to that frame before doing your actions